# Assigning a value from xstring

Tags: expansion, xstring

I'm trying to write some basic validation of user input to a command `\noinsuit` which takes two parameters, an integer in [0, 13] and a letter indicating the suit.

So I expect `\noinsuit{1}{C}` to be valid and both `\noinsuit{Q}{C}` and `\noinsuit{1}{Q}` to be invalid.  That's working fine, but I'm having a problem using `xstring`'s `\StrLeft{#1}{1}` to test if the first character is an integer.  The following MWE prints its value correctly but if I uncomment the test line it throws

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\xs_StrLeft__ ...ef \xs_arg_ii {#2}\edef \xs_call 
                                                  {\noexpand \xs_testopt {\n...
```

A problem with the expansion I suppose.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\singpl}{bad}
\newcommand{\test}{bad}

\NewDocumentCommand\noinsuit{mm}{%
    \renewcommand{\test}{\StrLeft{#1}{1}}
%   \IfInteger{\test}{\renewcommand{\singpl}{cards}}{[\PackageError{BridgeStyle : \noinsuit}{Invalid integer (#1)}{}]}%
    \IfEqCase{#1}{%
        {1}{\renewcommand{\singpl}{card}}%
    }
    \IfEqCase{#2}{%
        {C}{#1 \singpl{}\quad\test in Clubs}%
        {D}{#1 \singpl{} in Diamonds}%
        {H}{#1 \singpl{} in Hearts}%
        {S}{#1 \singpl{} in Spades}%
    }[\PackageError{BridgeStyle : \noinsuit}{Unknown suit (#2)}{}]%
}%

\begin{document}

\noinsuit{1}{C}

\noinsuit{2}{C}

%    \noinsuit{Q}{H}

%    \noinsuit{3}{Q}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to work fine for me. When I uncomment the last two lines I get `Package BridgeStyle : \noinsuit  Error: Unknown suit (Q)` which seems to be the correct result as `Q` is not a known suite. Perhaps one of your packages is out of date?  Also, if you want to save the value from an `xstring` macro, just use the optional last parameter. So instead of `\renewcommand{\test}{\StrLeft{#1}{1}}` use `\StrLeft{#1}{1}[\test]`.

Comment: @Peter Grill Thanks for that - saving the value as you suggest gets my live code working!  If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: egreg's answer already covers that and more...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `\StrLeft` inside the argument to `\IfInteger`. You're passing the instructions to build a string rather than the string.

Rather do

```
  \StrLeft{#1}{1}[\test]
  \IfInteger{\test}
    {\renewcommand{\singpl}{cards}}
    {\PackageError{BridgeStyle : \noinsuit}{Invalid integer (#1)}{}}%
```

On the other hand, you can get more control by using `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\noinsuit{mm}
 {
  \bridgestyle_noinsuit_checknumber:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \bridgestyle_noinsuit_checknumber:nn
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { \A [0-9]{1,2} \Z } { #1 }
   {% we have one or two digits
    \int_compare:nTF { #1 <= 13 }
     {% the integer is between 0 and 13
      \bridgestyle_noinsuit_checksuit:nn { #1 } { #2 }
     }
     {% error
      \bridgestyle_noinsuit_invalid:nn { integer } { #1 }
     }
   }
   {% invalid input for the integer
    \bridgestyle_noinsuit_invalid:nn { integer } { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \bridgestyle_noinsuit_checksuit:nn
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { \A [CDHS] \Z } { #2 }
   {% valid suit
    #1~card\int_compare:nF { #1=1 } {s}~in~\bridgestyle_suit:n { #2 }
   }
   {% invalid suit
    \bridgestyle_noinsuit_invalid:nn { suit } { #2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \bridgestyle_suit:n
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {C}{Clubs}
    {D}{Diamonds}
    {H}{Hearts}
    {S}{Spades}
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \bridgestyle_noinsuit_invalid:nn
 {
  \PackageError{bridgestyle}{(\string\noinsuit)~invalid~#1~(#2)}{}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noinsuit{0}{D}

\noinsuit{1}{C}

\noinsuit{2}{C}

\noinsuit{Q}{H}

\noinsuit{3}{Q}

\noinsuit{14}{H}

\end{document}
```

The console output is

```
! Package bridgestyle Error: (\noinsuit) invalid integer (Q).

See the bridgestyle package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.65 \noinsuit{Q}{H}

? 

! Package bridgestyle Error: (\noinsuit) invalid suit (Q).

See the bridgestyle package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.67 \noinsuit{3}{Q}

? 

! Package bridgestyle Error: (\noinsuit) invalid integer (14).

See the bridgestyle package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.69 \noinsuit{14}{H}

?
```

The printed output is

[image]